# MVC Partial View WebGrid not reloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have the following View and Controller:

View:

```
<div class="searchPastTransactions">
<p>
    <label for="start">From:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("from")
              .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
        )

        <label for="end">To:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("to")
              .Events(e => e.Change("endChange"))
        )
</p>
    <button class="k-button" id="showGrid">Search</button>
</div>

<script>

    function startChange() {
        var endPicker = $("#to").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            startDate = this.value();

        if (startDate) {
            startDate = new Date(startDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
            endPicker.min(startDate);
        }
    }

    function endChange() {
        var startPicker = $("#from").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            endDate = this.value();

        if (endDate) {
            endDate = new Date(endDate);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
            startPicker.max(endDate);
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        $("#showGrid").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PastTransactionsPartial", "InventoryTransactions")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    dateFrom: $('#from').val(),
                    dateTo: $('#to').val(),
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divPastTransactions').replaceWith(result);
                },
                error: function () { alert("Please specify from and to dates"); }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="divPastTransactions"  ></div>
```

Partial View:

```
<div id="gridContent">
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
        defaultSort: "InventoryTransactionCreatedDateTime",
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        canPage: true,
        canSort: true,
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent"
    );
    grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
}

    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "gridTable",
        headerStyle: "gridHead", 
        footerStyle:"gridFooter",
        rowStyle:"gridRow", 
        alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionID",
                header: "ID",
                style: "fiftyCenter"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionType.InventoryTransactionTypeName",
                header: "Transaction Type",
                style: "fiftyCenter"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryType.InventoryTypeName",
                header: "Type",
                style: "fiftyCenter"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName:"Supplier",
                header:"Supplier",
                style: "eightyCenter",
                format: @<text>  @if (@item.Supplier !=null) { <span> @item.Supplier.SupplierName </span> } </text> 
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionDate",
                header: "Transaction Date",
                format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.InventoryTransactionDate),
                style: "fiftyCenter"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionReceipt",
                header: "Receipt/ Invoice No.",
                style: "fiftyCenter"
            ),

            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionQuantity",
                header: "Quantity",
                style: "fiftyRight",
                format: (item) => string.Format("{0:N2}", item.InventoryTransactionQuantity)
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionPrice",
                header: "Price per Item",
                style: "fiftyRight",
                format: (item) => string.Format("{0:N2}", item.InventoryTransactionPrice)
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionBy",
                header: "Transaction By",
                style: "fiftyCenter"
            ),

            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionRemarks",
                header: "Remarks",
                style: "twohundred"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionCreatedDateTime",
                header: "Created On"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionCreatedBy",
                header: "User"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionCancelled",
                header: "Cancelled"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "InventoryTransactionCancelledSourceID",
                header: "Cancelled ID"
            ),
            grid.Column(
                columnName:"InventoryTransactionID", 
                header: " ",
                format: @<text> @if (!@item.InventoryTransactionCancelled && @item.InventoryTransactionCancelledSourceID == null && User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
                                { @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "CancelTransaction", new { id = item.InventoryTransactionID}) } </text>
            )
        )
    )
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PastTransactionsPartial(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
        {
            var inventorytransactions = db.InventoryTransactions.Include(i => i.InventoryTransactionType).Include(i => i.InventoryType).Include(i => i.Supplier).Where(i => i.InventoryTransactionDate >= dateFrom && i.InventoryTransactionDate <= dateTo);
            return PartialView("_PastTransactionsPartial", inventorytransactions.ToList());
        }
```

The problem I have is, after the first time loading the partial view, I am unable to replace it with new result. I have to refresh and then perform the search once again otherwise the grid will always shows old results.

**Update:**
Unable to find a solution for the issue. In the end I disable the search button after the search and user need to reload the page for another search.

Comment: Did you tried to clean the container div and then load the data inside?

Comment: @Fals I already try to put `success: function (result) { $('#divPastTransactions').empty();
                    $('#divPastTransactions').replaceWith(result);
                },` but with no luck...

Comment: Did you checked out the Response from the second search? Looks like theres a empty response comming! Look at Firebug and Chrome consoles for JS erros too, theres something messing up with the data, if theres some data returning from the Action!

Comment: @Fals There is a response. I did debug trace to check it. I tried in IE as well, but the same issue. Somehow the new result does not want to replace the old result

Comment: Not sure if you already solved the problem, but try declaring @grid.GetHtml inside the div gridContent, and move var grid = new WebGrid outside the div.